# How to calculate R2/Q2 for Matrices

Tags: python, matrix, pca, prediction, cross-validation

I'm trying to calculate `R2` and `Q2` scores for `PCA`, but I'm having a hard time calculating `r2_scores` from scratch for matrices. For `R2`, if I use `r2_score` from `sklearn`, I get the expected result (tested against results in SIMCA), but I cannot use this same method for `Q2` scores, so I would like help in how to find the numerator in the second term of `R2/Q2 (1 - num/SST)`. Please excuse my novice code, any help you can provide is very appreciated!

```
cov_matrix = X.cov().values
total_variation = cov_matrix.trace() 

q2 = []
r2 = []

for pc in range(1, min(X.shape[1], 11)):  
  ### Create folds
  kf = KFold(n_splits=7, shuffle=True)
  
  ### Fit PCA model on data
  pca = PCA(pc)
  scores = pca.fit_transform(X)

  ### Reconstruct X dataset from scores
  recon = pca.inverse_transform(scores)

  ### Create residual matrix
  res = X - recon
  
  ### Using sklearn, the correct R2 score is returned
  #r2_i = r2_score(X, recon)
  ### Incorrect implementation of R2
  r2_i = 1 - np.linalg.norm(res)/total_variation
  ### Append current result to list of R2 scores for each principle component count
  r2.append(r2_i)

  mat_test = np.zeros(shape=X.shape)

  for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X) :
    ### split data into train and test sets
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]

    ### Fit PCA model on training data
    pca_cv = PCA(pc)
    pca_cv.fit(X_train)
    
    ### Calculate scores of test set and reconstruct the data
    scores_test = pca_cv.transform(X_test)
    recon_test = pca_cv.inverse_transform(scores_test)
    
    ### Save the reconstructed data
    mat_test[test_index, :] = recon_test 

  ### Create residual matrix
  res = X - mat_test

  ### Calculate PRESS (incorrect)
  press = np.linalg.norm(res)
    
  ### calculate Q2 score (doesn't give correct values)
  #q2_i = r2_score(X, mat_test)
  ### calculate Q2 score (doesn't give correct values)
  q2.append(1 - press/total_variation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the trace for the X matrix which is correct, but then the norm for the residual, which is the square root and so incorrect.

if you update the calculation to
`press = np.cov(res).trace()`
it will return the correct value